# JSON.parse doesn't work in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I am using ajax before page load for getting some Json string. From my handler I return string that formatted json. And I must use as json in javascript. To do that I try JSON.parse(myJsonString) and it don't work. When I alert that it doesn't show up. Where am I going wrong?

```
var     geojsonObject2 ;
$.ajax({
        url: "LoadHandler.ashx",
        success: function getFromDBCallback(geojsonObject) {
            //var temp='['+geojsonObject+']'// I also try that, it don't work
            var obj = JSON.parse(geojsonObject);
            alert(obj);// for checking but nothing show up here?
            geojsonObject2 = obj;
        },
        async: false
    });
```

and this is my Handler:

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
        #region json string
        string geojsonObject = @"
            {
            'type': 'FeatureCollection',
            'crs': {
                'type': 'name',
                'properties': {
                    'name': 'EPSG:4326'
                }
            },
            'features': [
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {
                        'any-property': 'feature1'
                    },
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'Point',
                        'coordinates': [21.54967, 38.70250]
                    }
                },
                {
                    'type': 'Feature',
                    'properties': {
                        'any-property': 'feature2'
                    },
                    'geometry': {
                        'type': 'LineString',
                        'coordinates': [
                            [21.54967, 38.70250], [22.54967, 39.70250]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
        ";
        #endregion
        //context.Response.Write(js.Serialize(geojsonObject));
        context.Response.Write(geojsonObject);
    }
```

Comment: That's not JSON, this is why you shouldn't  write JSON by hand.

Comment: run this `console.log(geojsonObject);`. What result did you get?

Comment: try replacing single-quotes with double-quotes in geojsonObject

Comment: actually I don't write this JSON by hand. I found it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32789411/adding-geojson-layer-to-openlayers-3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing single-quotes with doubles quotes as below, JSON.parse works if attribute names and values if they are enclosed in double-quotes:

```
string geojsonObject = @"
        {
        ""type"": ""FeatureCollection"",
        ""crs"": {
            ""type"": ""name"",
            ""properties"": {
                ""name"": ""EPSG:4326""
            }
        }...."
```